# Figure "name.jpg" mysteriously shows up!

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

[image: name.jpg is incorrectly on all pictures, on left in this case...]

> Hi I'm debugging my Schools Thesis template, and name.jpg of figures I import are mysteriously showing up.  I have included the caption definition (I think) and the code I used to input image.

thesis.cls

```
 \long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\csname fnum@#1\endcsname.\space\ignorespaces #2}%
    \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
    \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
```

body.tex

```
               \begin{figure}[!h]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]Chapter1Figures/name.jpg}
                \caption{words go here
                \label{fig:ENERGYbySOURCE}}
            \end{figure}
```

> The body.tex seems pretty straightforward, but I don't understand most of .cls coding.
>
> "name.jpg" is also showing up NEXT to one of my figures, in one case, very odd....

Comment: You have spaces in the name of the file; add quotes around it.

Comment: "name with space".jpg Got it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Look at the line `\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]Chapter1Figures/name.jpg}` of body.tex. I suppose, an opening curly brace  before the uppercase C of the directory name "Chapter1Figures"is missing. Should be: `\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Chapter1Figures/name.jpg}`